# How do I right-align an image in a GitBook?

Tags: markdown, gitbook

I am working on a GitBook using the web-based editor at www.gitbook.com.  I would like to have an inline image that is right justified.  If doing this in HTML, an example would be:

```
<img src="..." align="right">
```

I've been able to center an image with "center" tags, but haven't been able to do anything else to them.  Any align or style attributes get stripped from the image in the preview pane.  I've read the markdown guide, and searched Google and Stackoverflow with no luck.

Is it possible to control image alignment via markdown or HTML in a GitBook via the web-based editor?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to control image alignment via markdown (or at least via the markdown the gitbook uses).

However it is possible via HTML. You need to write it like in your example

```
<img src="..." align="right">
```

With this you can easily align images or change the size. You only need to ignore the Markdown syntax for this kind of images and use only the HTML syntax

Comment: Have you tried that to confirm it works?  As per my OP, all align attributes are stripped out of my img tag and that doesn't work.  That is, unless GitBook rolled out a recent update that fixed it.

Comment: Okay, thats strange. I've tried the whole thing on my own gitbook (local gitbook with `.md` files). I do not use the web-based editor!

Comment: But I've tried it fast for the web-based editor with exactly the code in your OP. It works fine for me. Maybe there has been a change to previous versions.